# Apache delivers images with artifacts on ubuntu 18.04 with mounted image directory

Tags: php, image, apache

I have a strange issue with artifacts in pictures delivered via apache2.4 to the web browser. Our comany uses a central picture storage for all the product images. This directory is mounted into the webserver under mnt/medamazonbild. I created a symbolic link, which points into the web directory under img/artikel. This worked and the folder is fully accessible.

But as soon as I request a picture from the directory via chrome or firefox under:

172.17.1.27/img/artikel/70399.jpg

the output is delivered with artifacts.

[image: Apache delivers the picture with artifacts.]

For test purposes I tried to deliver the image via PHP in image.php:

```
if (isset($_GET["img"])) {
    // get image name
    $img = filter_var($_GET["img"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // path of image with name and suffix
    $path = '/var/www/html/public/img/artikel/' . $img;

    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    readfile($path);
}
```

The result is the image without artifacts as it should be:

[image: The output with the readfile function delivers the expected image]

I don't want to process the image output for all the images with php, because I'm afraid of performance decreases. **How can I get a solution for apache to deliver the images as expected? Where is the error?**

**Setup**:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Apache 2.4
- Mounted directory with pictures under: mnt/medamazonbild
- Symbolic link from mnt/medamazonbild into webroot img/artikel

Comment: If you save the glitchy file to your computer, and open it there, is it messed up there as well? Or just in the browser?

Comment: It's just messed up in the browser. Also the appearance of the artifacts change from request to request. So it couldn't be a file problem.

Comment: Is it possible you've got something like mod_pagespeed that's trying to compress the image and doing a poor job of it?

Comment: Unfortunately no. It's the default apache 2.4 configuration without any additional compression.

Comment: I copied the image from the mounted directory into the webroot img directory. The output of the copied image from the img directory is free of artifacts.

Comment: When responding to @ceejayoz 's first comment, did you actually save the glitchy image from Chrome itself (i.e. use the 'save image as' function), or just try opening the file on disk?  If the latter, try the former and open the saved file on disk.  Alternatively, try grabbing both URLs using a utility like cURL and compare the results.

Comment: @zinga I took it direct from the server disk with filezilla. Now I tried again and saved it via chrome. The saved image is also broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same type of glitchs on my images.
I'm using the official docker image php:7.3-apache [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/php)
To fix this issue I added `EnableSendfile on` to my .htaccess (I think it works the same as if you add it in your httpd.conf)

Answer (score 2):

I just had this exact same issue on a Kubernetes cluster at Azure (AKS).

We updated from 1.16.X to 19.X.X recently, and images on our Wordpress sites stopped working. Trying to open the image path in Chrome, it downloaded an corrupt file instead of showing the image.

After one hole day of debugging, we made the following observations:

- Serving images from anywhere but inside a mount worked as expected
- We made sure the fileshare was mounted with the exact same permissions as folders and files outside the mount, where serving images where working
- When looking at the headers (curl -X HEAD -I https://path) they where as expected
- Images from the mount was altered upon download - it added some artifacts to the beginning of the image (something that looked like HTTP headers in plaintext) and when comparing the source code of the image, it seemed to contain some wrongly encoded content, make the image look like the one from OP

The simple solution of adding `EnableSendfile on` to our `.htaccess` solved the problem - thanks a lot @botf!

We don't have any clue why (maybe some Apache experts can shed some light) but apparently Apache2 have some issues with reading the files from our mounts.
We have other services on our AKS cluster running NGINX which are working fine.