# http Images over Ubuntu 18.x + Apache 2 seem corrupted/ incomplete

Tags: image, http, apache2, ubuntu-18.04

I have hosted images over Apache 2.4 over Ubuntu 18.04 and they appear incomplete/ corrupted. The images appear in different colors sometimes as shown below. The images are mounted from another storage drive. Anyone faced this before?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcGcE.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/23eEQ.png

Comment: Similar issue on same OS and Apache versions

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54946454/apache-delivers-images-with-artifacts-on-ubuntu-18-04-with-mounted-image-directo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 16.04 solved the issue.